# Access codecommit in account A from lambda function in account B?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

**Usecase**

I have a codecommit REPO in account A. I have my lambda in account B. I need to access the codecommit repo from my lambda that is in account B.

**What I did**

1. I created a role with name `CrossAccountRole` in Account A with managed
   `codedcommitReadOnlypolicy` and assigned it with a trust
   relationship of account B, so that account B can assume the role.
2. In Account B i created a `ASSUMEROLE` policy like this

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "sts:AssumeRole",
                   "sts:GetFederationToken"
               ],
               "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::134952096518:role/CrossAccountRole"
           },
           {
               "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": "sts:GetCallerIdentity",
               "Resource": "*"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   and attached it to my user permissions.
3. And also i created a basic execution role for the lambda function
   and attached the `ASSUMEROLE` policy to it.

I am sure everything is working fine . Because when i tried switch role from console in AccountB i can able to see the `codecommit Repos` that are in AccountA.

But still i cant able to connect to the AccountA codecommit repos from my lambda function in accountB.

My lambda function looks like this in accountB

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-south-1';
var codecommit = new AWS.CodeCommit({apiVersion: '2015-04-13'});
var params = {
  commitId: 'xxx', 
  repositoryName: 'new' 
};
  var sts = new AWS.STS();
  var sts_params = {
    RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:role/CrossAccountRole",
    RoleSessionName: "ThisCanBeAnyName"
  };
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
try {
       const creds = await sts.assumeRole(sts_params).promise();
       console.log(creds);
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: creds.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: creds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: creds.Credentials.SessionToken
    });
   const response = await codecommit.getCommit(params).promise();
   const email = response.commit.committer.email;
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

I am getting error like `new Repository not exist`. Since it is searching in the account B it is through this error.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With respective to the IAM roles all are good. Some changes need to be done in my lambda code. In my lambda code i need to pass the `temporary credentials` to the service that is `codecommit`, which i didnt do in the above code. SO, here is the working sample

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-south-1';
var params = {
   commitId: 'abc',
  repositoryName: 'new' 
};
  var sts = new AWS.STS();
  var sts_params = {
    RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::xx:role/CrossAccountRole",
    RoleSessionName: "crossaccountRole"
  };
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
try {
      const creds = await sts.assumeRole(sts_params).promise();
      const accessparams2 = {
    accessKeyId: creds.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: creds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: creds.Credentials.SessionToken,
  };
   const codecommit = await new AWS.CodeCommit(accessparams2);
   const response = await codecommit.getCommit(params).promise();
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Hope it will be helpful for the others